# Evolus Pencil Export page as HTML

Tags: export, ubuntu-14.04, evolus-pencil

I am trying to export a wireframe that I've made using Evolus Pencil to page/HTML template but it is not working. It freezes while exporting and does not provide any feedback about it or even raises any error message.

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 64 bits with .deb version. The Evolus Pencil version is 2.0.5 and I've also tried installed the latest one in another machine. Does anyone have idea what is happening?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The solution can be found [here](http://thegeekettespeaketh.com/2013/03/solved-cant-export-png-from-evolus-pencil/).

Tested in Ubuntu 14.04 x64 with Pencil installed as deb (just like you).

Follow these steps:

1- Download [xulrunner](http://ftp.mozilla.org/pub/mozilla.org/xulrunner/releases/16.0.2/runtimes/xulrunner-16.0.2.en-US.linux-x86_64.tar.bz2)

2- Extract in `/opt` (root required)

3- Edit `/usr/bin/pencil` with a text editor (root required)

4- Change `/usr/bin/firefox` to `/opt/xulrunner/xulrunner` and save

It should be working now, it does for me.